# Performance of having a $rootScope.$on in a repeated child directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Forgive me if this has been asked else where. I couldn't find anything answering this and I may just be overthinking something and thinking it is a problem when it isn't.

```
<customer ng-repeat="customer in customers"> </customers>
```

Each customer (~20) has

```
      var customerListener = $rootScope.$on("request:customerUpdated", function(event, customerId, orders) {
         if ($scope.customer.id === customerId) {
             $scope.customer.orders = orders;
         }
      });
      $scope.$on("$destroy", customerListener);
```

(Above is slightly modified/pseudo code from my site)

How big of a performance hit is it having so many event listeners, and is it something I need to worry about/abstract the event to parent directive? Or someone direct me to a performance article on listeners in angular?

Thanks

Comment: Attaching `$on` listeners to `$rootScope` will create memory leaks if they are not removed properly. Attaching them to `$scope` is a better strategy.

Comment: Using something like this:
`$scope.$on("$destroy", customerListener);`

Comment: Use `$scope.$on` instead of `$rootScope.$on` where possible. The main problem with using global event listeners is that events get missed when a listener is added after an event is broadcast. AngularJS is an MV* (Model View Whatever) architecture. Events change the Model, then the View is rendered from the Model. The `ng-repeat` directive works best when the entire model is defined before the DOM is rendered. Events should only be communicated upward using expresson binding. Use of the global event bus should be avoided.